# Create multiple buttons on image or insert grid over image

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a picture with the numbers 1, 2, and 3 on it. I want to be able to put a clickable grid over each number that will change the picture when clicked. How can I achieve this. I thought about puting a grid inside the image tag but it didnt work. Any ideas?

Here is my current xaml and a pic of what it looks like.  I just want to have a button at each number that hovers over the image and are clickable, but I am having trouble making this happen.

```
<Grid Name="marsecLevel1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0 0 10 90" Width="220" Height="82">
    <Button Height="30" Width="30" Cursor="Hand" Margin="3 5 0 0" MouseLeftButtonDown="marsecLevel1Button_Click"></Button>
    <Image Source="Images/marseclevel1.png" Visibility="Visible" Stretch="Fill"></Image>
</Grid>

<Grid Name="marsecLevel2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0 0 10 90" Width="220" Height="82">
    <Button Height="30" Width="30" Cursor="Hand" Margin="93 5 0 0" MouseLeftButtonDown="marsecLevel2Button_Click"></Button>
    <Image Source="Images/marseclevel2.png" Visibility="Visible" Stretch="Fill"></Image>
</Grid>

<Grid Name="marsecLevel3" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0 0 10 90" Width="220" Height="82">
    <Button Height="30" Width="30" Cursor="Hand" Margin="173 5 0 0" MouseLeftButtonDown="marsecLevel3Button_Click"></Button>
    <Image Source="Images/marseclevel3.png" Visibility="Visible" Stretch="Fill"></Image>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe if I use <Canvas>?  I am not sure...

Comment: Just change the order in what you declare buttons and image (first is under the second so you click goes to the image not to the button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I can think of involves finding the position of your button background rectangle by trial and error. You could do this by setting a button to the desired size and adjusting your margins until it was in the right place. For example,

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/path/to/image.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Button Width="100" Height="50" Background="Blue" Margin="10,10,10,10"/>
</Grid>
```

Then adjust the margin as desired...

Once you've got your position you create your button rectangle something like this

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/path/to/image.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/path/to/image.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </StackPanel.Background>
        <Button/>
        <Button/>
        <Button/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```